# spring rest api unable to set Set-Cookie

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, setcookie

***Environment***

springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'

Linux : 18.01 LTS

***Context***

I have the current method in controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "")
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody @Valid LoginCredentials loginCredentials) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
        .header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, "Authorization=" + "Bearer " + token)
        .build();
}
```

and my cors are configured right

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("*")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowedMethods("*")
        .allowCredentials(true);
}
```

I also get on postman that the headers are got right

[image]

Still the header set-cookie is not sent.

The same happens when i use angular app to send the request with

```
    return this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, loginCred, {withCredentials: true});
```

As you see, with credentials is set to true.
still I do not get my Set-cookie header.

***Question***

How can I have my header on the frontend (Angular or postman) ?

Answer (score 3):

After hours of seraching, I found the main cause.

My frontent runs on localhost:4200
My backend runs on  localhost:8090

when backend sends set cookie, google chrome blocks it, as the cookie is set by third party domain.

it can be inactivated in  Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Block third-party cookies and site data)

***Work around***

get the token in frontend as the body of the response, and set it there, by mean of frontend business logic (local storage, or set cookie)